# PHP - member encapsulation returns strange reference

Tags: php, reference

I have a class which has a private member `$content`. This is wrapped by a get-method:

```
class ContentHolder
{
    private $content;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->content = "";
    }

    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }
}
$c = new ContentHolder();
$foo = array();
$foo['c'] = $c->getContent();
```

Now `$foo['c']` is a reference to `content`, which is what I don't understand. How can I get the value? Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I just tried your code and `$foo['c']` is not a reference to `$content`. (Assigning a new value to `$foo['c']` does not affect `$content`.)

By default all PHP functions/methods pass arguments by value and return by value. To return by reference you would need to use this syntax for the method definition:

```
public function &getContent()
{
    return $this->content;
}
```

And this syntax when calling the method:

```
$foo['c'] = &$c->getContent();
```

See http://ca.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php.

Comment: just a note, php5 does return objects by reference, but anything else by value as you note.

Answer (score 3):

i'm not quite understanding your question. say you changed:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->content = "test";
}

$c = new ContentHolder();
$foo = array();
$foo['c'] = $c->getContent();

print $foo['c'];          // prints "test"
print $c->getContent();   // prints "test"
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, you don't say: "`$foo = new array();`"
Instead, you simply say: "`$foo = array();`"

I ran your code (PHP 5.2.6) and it seems to work fine.  I tested it by dumping the array:

```
var_dump($foo);
```

This outputs:

```
array(1) {
  ["c"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

I can also simple use `echo`:

```
echo "foo[c] = '" . $foo['c'] . "'\n";
```

This outputs:

```
foo[c] = ''
```

Comment: thanks, but that was a simple typo and fixing it does not affect the behaviour described

Comment: Ok, I went on and did more tests.  Still cannot observe any problem.